# Spring Framework usage

Tags: spring

Usually how would each of the module in the Spring framework is used in a web project. I am trying to get an idea about it, as i am on a fast track to learn and implement it.

I know it does have below modules in it, but any help in explaining why and where they are useful would help me a lot in learning.

The Core container module
   Application context module
   AOP module (Aspect Oriented Programming)
   JDBC abstraction and DAO module
   O/R mapping integration module (Object/Relational)
   Web module 
   MVC framework module

Thanks,
SS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This page might be helpful to you: [Introduction to Spring Framework: Modules](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-modules).  Spring provides a very good, free [reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/index.html) that covers much of this and more.

Here's my short summary of why you would use any of these:

**Core** - This allows you to use the [dependency-injection pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to construct your application, which can greatly simplify your classes and unit testing.

**Application Context** - This provides support code for many common problems.

**AOP** - This provides support for [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), which can help you separate "cross cutting concerns" like logging and transaction management from your business logic.

**JDBC** - Provides support code that makes JDBC easier to use.

**OR/Mapping** - Provides support code to integrate popular ORM frameworks into Spring.

**Web MVC** - Provides support for the [Model-View-Controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) using Spring beans (several other frameworks, such as JSF, provide this as well).

To sum it up, the Core module contains most of what people think of when they think of Spring, and the other modules provide code help you implement your application in a cleaner, more supportable way, without re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

> The Core container module
>
> Application context module

This is the dependency injection piece - the bean factory and application context where you wire bean dependencies together.

> AOP module (Aspect Oriented
>   Programming)

Cross-cutting concerns like logging, security, transactions, etc. are handled using either Spring interceptors (dynamically generated proxies) or AspectJ (byte code generation).

> JDBC abstraction and DAO module

Persistence using a lightweight JDBC template that takes the boilerplate out of using JDBC.

> O/R mapping integration module
>   (Object/Relational)

For folks who prefer Hibernate.

> Web module MVC framework module

Web MVC module for JSP, browser based user interfaces based on front controller and view dispatchers.